# Which of the following is NOT true regarding eigenvalues?

Tags: self-study, pca, spss, computational-statistics, eigenvalues

I am having a hard time trying to figure out the correct answer to this question. Any insight? I don't understand this at all.

> Which of the following is **NOT** true regarding eigenvalues?
>
> Option 1: An eigenvalue indicates the amount of variance in the input data a component accounts for
>
> Option 2: Any component with an eigenvalue greater than 1 is formally significant
>
> Option 3: Eigenvalues are ordered in decreasing size
>
> Option 4: There are a number of ways to decide how many are meaningful

My thoughts: Option 1 is the definition (I think), but do eigenvalues indicate variance in INPUT data or in general? Option 2, in the lecture our professor was saying that SPSS will automatically assume that eigenvalues greater than 1 are significant in some way, but what does "FORMALLY" significant mean? Option 3, this is true when inputting data in SPSS. Option 4, this is also true, you can use Monte-Carlo analysis or scree plot.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Speaking in terms of PCA, using SPSS as the data analysis program.

Comment: +1 This is a ghastly question (no fault of yours) because eigenvalues have a well-established meaning for which all these options make little sense. We must suppose you are working in a PCA context, but even then it's important to indicate what matrix these are the eigenvalues of (for option 1) and even which software is being used (because the ordering may be software-dependent). You are also right to point out the vagueness of terms like "formally significant" and "meaningful." If "not true" includes "makes no sense," "is ambiguous," or "it depends," then *all four options* should be chosen!

Comment: Thank you for saying that, it really is a horrible question. It is in terms of PCA and we are using SPSS to analyze data.

Comment: Note that options 2 and 4 are sort-of contradictory.  Since you realize option 4 is true, it seems unlikely (to try to think in the context of the question) that option 2 is true.